# creating instance of belongs_to model not showing up in it's associated objects list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, polymorphic-associations, belongs-to

I've created two models with the below associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class Student < Role
end

class Tutor < Role
end
```

However when I create a new child role, I assume it would get associated to the model it has the belongs to for.

Such as:

```
Tutor.create(:user_id => user_id)
```

I would expect:

```
#some user @user
@user.roles
```

to have an array containing a Tutor. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user is just some instance of the user object

Comment: Yes I understand. But did you instantiate it somewhere? If so how did you do it? For example, do you have something like `@user = User.find(params[:id])`?

Comment: Well I'm working off objects that were previously created but yea that's how they were instantiated when they were created

Answer (score 1):

Once you start using Single Table Inheritance, than the Tutor that you created isn't a role, as far as active-record is concerned for this type of query.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :tutors
end

@user = User.first
@user.roles
=> []

@user.tutors
=> [#<Tutor id: 1, user_id: 1, type: "Tutor", created_at: "2012-10-26 18:15:16", updated_at: "2012-10-26 18:15:16">]
```

If you want to get a list of all roles that your users may have:

```
Role.where(user_id: @user.id).all
```

`[#<Tutor id: 1, user_id: 1, type: "Tutor", created_at: "2012-10-26 18:15:16", updated_at: "2012-10-26 18:15:16">, #<Student id: 2, user_id: 1, type: "Student", created_at: "2012-10-26 18:18:32", updated_at: "2012-10-26 18:18:32">]`

Comment: I see. So either I get roles as you listed or I would have to change the type of inheritance? What if I wanted it to function as I listed before. What changes would I have to make?

Comment: You can not use inheritance. That's probably the only way.